# Find the minimum positive root of $\sin{3x}=a$ ($a>0)$, given that there exist two roots differing by $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The problem is quite simple, I just need to make sure there is no quick and obvious way I am missing.

> Find the minimum positive root of the equation $\sin{3x}=a$ ($a>0$) given that there exist two roots such that their difference equals $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

How I solved the problem:
We know that the equation has roots: $x_1$ and $\frac{\pi}{4}+x_1$. Plugging that into the original equation we get:
$$\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{4} + 3x_1\right) = a$$
from which we can find the positive value of $a$ that equals $\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{2}$. 
Having the value of $a$, we can now plug it into $\sin{3x}=a$ and find the desired minimum positive root.

> Is there a better way (without graphs) to solve this problem?

Comment: Don't you think you should add that between the two roots that differ from $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ there is no other root?. One can do that between  two roots such that their difference is $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ there exist many other roots.

Answer (score 2):

The smaller positive roots occur in the interval $\left[0,\frac{1}{3}\pi\right]$ when $a>0$. If the smallest is $x_1$, then because of symmetry, the next smallest will be $\frac{\pi}{3}-x_1$.

If the two roots are to be a distance apart of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ then

$$ \left(\frac{\pi}{3}-x_1\right)-x_1=\frac{\pi}{4} $$

So $x_1=\frac{\pi}{24}$.

ADDENDUM: If you do not wish to argue from the symmetry of the graph about $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$ you may instead note that

$$\sin\left(3\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-x_1\right)\right)=\sin(3x_1)$$

Comment: In general, the period of $y=\sin(Bx)$ is $\frac{2\pi}{B}$, so the period of $y=\sin(3x)$ is $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. A sine graph is positive on the first half of its period and negative on the second half. For $y=\sin(3x)-a$ for $a>0$ the y values will be decreased by an amount $a$ causing some values in the first half of the period to drop below $0$.

Comment: Wayles Bales, Could you pl tell me how your addendum is helpful in finding the root. ?

Comment: @Epsilon, it helps to understand the symmetry around $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$ and thus deduce that if one of the roots is $x_1$ then the second one (we are looking for the minimum values i.e. on $[0;\frac{\pi}{3}]$. Knowing that the difference should be equal to $\frac{\pi}{4}$, we can find the value of $x_1$.